# How to move existed image to another folder in Yii?

Tags: php, file, file-upload, yii

I have a directory already existed some images. Now I would like to move some of those image to another folder.

```
if(file_exists(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../images/Banner/temp/'.$ads->image)) 
                    print_r('file existed');
```

The above code shows file is existed there, But while I try to move That file to another folder such as

```
move_uploaded_file(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../images/Banner/temp/'.$ads->image, Yii::app()->basePath.'/../images/Banner/new/'.$ads->image);
```

Though, it's not working . Where I have made mistake?
Thanks in advance.... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php

rename(Yii::app()->basePath.'/../images/Banner/temp/'.$ads->image, Yii::app()->basePath.'/../images/Banner/new/'.$ads->image);

?>
```

Comment: Thanks buddy for your quick attention and It really works. Now I feel stupid for a while..  :)